# Python: error reading csv (with error message: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 5, saw 63))

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I've downloaded some data from the world bank in csv format, but when I try and read it in jupyter I get the error message: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 5, saw 63."

Anyone know how to resolve this (without adjusting the original dataset, which is very large)
I've tried `error_bad_lines=False` but this does not work

The pictures of the csv and full output are below: 
[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wubSy.png)

[output first half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFNKH.png)

[output second half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56uFq.png)

Comment: Show us line 5 please

Comment: sorry was in a rush, have attached images

Comment: I think you'll need to include some of the actual csv file - at least the header line and line 5.

Answer (score 1):

Your header row actually starts on line 5... (In other words, The CSV data rows start at line 5)  Delete the first 4 lines from your file so that your header `"Country Name", "Country Description", ...etc` is the first line in the file.

This is quite common to have a small header on top of CSV files.

Or *maybe* you can configure `jupyter` to start the import at line 5, but I have no idea how to use `jupyter`

Comment: @DDFF I'm glad it helped.  Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please mark any Answer as accepted if it truly fixed your problem.